# how do i fix first_program.__main__ error in python

Tags: python

whenever I try to run my program this error comes up:

```
/Users/kwlong/PycharmProjects/first_program/venv/bin/python -m first_program
```

How do I fix this error? I'm using a Mac, and my code is just:

```py
print('hi')
```

Comment: That's not an error message.

Comment: As @user2357112supportsMonica said, that's not an error message. It's just how you run your python program.

Comment: Well its not running the program and the message is in red also the end of it says 'first_program' is a package and cannot be directly executed
but idk Im new to python

Answer (score 0):

The `-m` means you are trying to execute this program as a module. Instead, try `python3 first_program.py`. Here, you should use `python3` instead of `python`, because Python 2 is pre-installed on Mac. Using `python` may confuse the terminal. Just for your information, the Python interpeter thinks that you are trying to run a module (as said before), and is trying to find `first_program/__main__.py`. However, you are just running a normal Python file, not a folder.